# What is "Type name requires specifier or qualifier" in Xcode 4.6.2?

Tags: xcode

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic);
@property (weak, nonatomic);

@end
```

I am getting the same error on both @property lines. It is telling me "Type name requires specifier or qualifier". This is under the ';' on both lines.

Please help!

Comment: Hint: Look at a `@property` declaration in some working code. Compare it to yours. Is there anything that yours is missing?

Comment: Check here for help: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not declaring your properties correctly, you need to tell it what kind of object you have and what the name is:

For example

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL *hasReadDocumentation;
```